# Modifying html/javascript code with httr

Tags: r, curl, httr

I'm trying to make a script which checks if someone has been to this school, using their [alumni directory](http://www.sciences-po.asso.fr/gene/main.php?base=1244). (You can use the name Francois Hollande (current French president) to see how it behaves)

As far as I can tell (for the "name" ("nom") button) I need to access this part of the HTML code :

```
<div class="annuaireRecherche-v2" style="">
  <span>Nom</span>
  <div class="select2-container select2-allowclear autocomplete" id="s2id_PersonneNom" style="min-width: 0;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
      <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-3">Derez</span>
      <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
      <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
        <b role="presentation"></b>
      </span>
    </a>
    <label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-3" id="s2id_autogen3" tabindex="0">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="PersonneNom" id="PersonneNom" class="autocomplete" style="min-width: 0px; display: none;" data-placeholder="Saisir un nom" data-multiple="" data-libelle="" value="Hollande" data-limit="" tabindex="-1" title="">
</div>
```

and in the last `<input>` tag, change the `value` attribute to the name I want to check.

Then I'll have to "click" somehow on the `afficher les résultats` (translation : `show results`) on the right. Relevant HTML code :

```
<div class="showResultsButton" style="text-align: center; display: block;">
  <a href="#" class="jqueryButton  ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" onclick="showResultList($('.shortResults')); return false;" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">
      Afficher les résultats
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And then I'll have to get to the `<div class="people clearfix">` tag and retrieve the `<a href="...">` tags :

```
<div class="people clearfix">
    <div class="tab_result" style="clear:both">
        <div class="ppl">       
            <div class="ppl-wrap clearfix" style="clear:both">
                <div class="ppl-image">
                    <a href="/profil/francois.hollande74" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="" src="/ressources/temp/100_120t121_153006959_inconnu.jpeg">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="ppl-content">
                    <h3>
                        <a href="/profil/francois.hollande74" target="_blank">Hollande  François</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="meta">D Service Public Promo 1974</p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                    <div class="ppl-content" style="float:right"></div>
                </div>
            <p class="buttons">
                <a class="button " href="/profil/francois.hollande74" target="_blank">
                    Voir le profil
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code so far :

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(foreach)

url        <- "http://www.sciences-po.asso.fr/gene/main.php?base=1244"    
response   <- GET(url)
doc        <- content(response, type="text/html", encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
parseddoc  <- htmlParse(doc)

# i have to modify the content of this 
xpathApply(parseddoc, "//*[@id='PersonneNom']/@value")
# then make sure it is sent to the server, retrieve the code sent back, etcaetera...
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone would stumble upon this question, I found two other packages to crawl websites : `rvest` and `RSelenium`. I went with `RSelenium` as it seemed to be the most straight forward : it opens your browser and you can see live what you're code is doing on the webpage.

Moreover, here are two links that I found very useful, the second one being a good intro to `RSelenium` :

http://ikkyle.com/webscraping_with_r.html

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r